# How can I set the Power button behavior for all users of a computer?

Tags: windows-xp, electrical-power

I have tablet PCs that are used by many users. Whenever a new user logs on to the tablet the power settings default to "When I close the lid of my portable computer" = "Standby". I want it to be "Do Nothing".

I can't set them from powercfg.exe. I've tried exporting the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\PowerCfg\CurrentPowerPolicy registry key and importing it on additional users.

I'm looking for a way to change the default to Do Nothing for anyone that uses the computer or at least run a program or script at logon that switches to do nothing at logon.

Answer (score 1):

In your registry under HKEY_USERS(the user profile you set power options on)\PowerCfg\GlobalPowerPolicy copy the Policies option into all the other users including .DEFAULT. This worked for me.

Comment: I think I've tried current user and local machine, but I don't remember if I tried .DEFAULT. I'll need to try that.

Comment: are they roaming profiles or local profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this kind of thing is to set up a user profile exactly the way you want for new users, then copy it to the default user profile. Anyone logging in on the machine for the first time will inherit that as their starting profile.

Comment: thats basicly what i wrote re said...

Comment: @xjerx - Not quite the same. Copying the registry key adjusts one item in the profile. What I suggested copies the entire profile, which is a lot more flexible and is the standard way of preparing default user profiles.

Comment: good point, just the single setting is all he is looking for.

Comment: The local default profile or the domain profile?
C:\documents and settings\Default User\
\\domain\NETLOGIN\Default User\

Comment: @Ed, good question. I've only ever done it with local profiles and never had an issue.